# How to move back and forth on a game board depending on random number (dice)?

Tags: javascript

This is what I got now...

```js
var max = 7;
var min = 1;

$('#dice').click(function() {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  $('.bordSquare').css({
    'backgroundColor': 'white'
  });
  $('#' + random).css({
    'backgroundColor': '#00ffec'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="bordSquare">1</div>
<div id="2" class="bordSquare">2</div>
<div id="3" class="bordSquare">3</div>
<div id="4" class="bordSquare">4</div>
<div id="5" class="bordSquare">5</div>
<div id="6" class="bordSquare">6</div>

<button id="dice">Dice</button>
```

With this code, the piece (the `bg` color) just goes to the randomly generated number, but I want to actually count from where it is and move that many squares (divs), also when it gets to the end, if the number is bigger to count back that many squares.

I think I somehow need to use an array and store the current position, increment that with the one from the "dice" and then update the "board", but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by count back you mean cycle back and start from 1 again, you can do this by storing the current position in a variable, then when the dice rolls, compute the new position by adding to `current` and taking the modulo of the dice value (see inline comments below).

```js
var max = 7;
var min = 1;
var current = 0;

$('#dice').click(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)); // between 0 and (max - min)
  var newPos = min + (current + random) % (max - min); // % ensures we stay within range
  console.log('current was ' + current, 'dice rolled ' + random, 'new position is ' + newPos);
  current = newPos;
  $('.bordSquare').css({
    'backgroundColor': 'white'
  });
  $('#' + newPos).css({ // update new position's bg color
    'backgroundColor': '#00ffec'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="bordSquare">1</div>
<div id="2" class="bordSquare">2</div>
<div id="3" class="bordSquare">3</div>
<div id="4" class="bordSquare">4</div>
<div id="5" class="bordSquare">5</div>
<div id="6" class="bordSquare">6</div>

<button id="dice">Dice</button>
```

If you just want to go backwards by the difference, you can subtract from `current` to compute `newPos`.

Comment: I really didn't understand the question.